# Mongoose schema multiple index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to set multiple indexes with mongoose. But only the first schema.index() works, independent if I change the order.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

schema.index({ name: 'text' })
schema.index({ email: 'text' }, { unique: true })
```

How can I set both schema.index()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mongoose supports setting indexes on the schema fields directly you can do it like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true  // <-- non text index here
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true  // <-- set unique here
  }
})

schema.index({ email: 'text', name: 'text'});  // <-- define text indexes
```

Comment: @Akiron Nice! How I set email as text?

Comment: I updated the answer with the additional way to define the `text` indexes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I was able to help.